# Angular Service not acting as singleton when injected in components despite using @Injectable({providedIn: 'root' }) decorator

Tags: angular, service, routes, navigation, singleton

I have a project which contains two modules (the default AppModule and the routing Module generated by angular cli when creating the project), two components that I have created and a service that I injected into the constructor of each component. I expected to have the same instance of the service (singleton each time I inject the service since it has the @Injectable({providedIn: 'root' }) decorator) but I keep getting a brand new instance of my service everytime when I navigate to each of my component. here is my code below :

**app.module.html**

```
\<router-outlet\>\</router-outlet\>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { Test2Component } from './test2/test2.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,
    Test2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { Test2Component } from './test2/test2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test1', component: TestComponent },
  { path: 'test2', component: Test2Component }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {

  constructor(private _testService: TestService) { }
}
```

**test2.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test2',
  templateUrl: './test2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test2.component.css']
})
export class Test2Component {

  constructor(private _testService: TestService) { }

}
```

**test.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  private date = new Date();

  constructor() {
    console.log("Inside the service ", this.date);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is indeed Singleton by the looks of the code.

Insert this to the app.component.html, and try the links:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="child-a">Child A</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="child-b">Child B</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I suspect that you try to check the two component with writing the url in the browser navbar, so you reload the application any time you think you are rerouting. Is that the case maybe?

I have created a working example of the routing and singleton service usage [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fk9pt3?file=src/app/app.component.html).

You can see that after several clicks, the constructor has run only once in the console:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works fine for me. I think it was because I wasn't using the router  module. Instead I was using the browser url bar and the reload button to change the url. this causes the application to reload everytime and all of my services to be reinstanciated. So when we assign a url in the navigation bar and hit enter for example we issue a request to the server to get the index.html file again which means the application is reboostraped again.

Answer (score 0):

Provide your test service in providers array in app.module.ts like this. To create singleton.
Providers:[TestService]

Comment: No need. "Beginning with Angular 6.0, the preferred way to create a singleton service is to set providedIn to root on the service's @Injectable() decorator. " from: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service

Comment: well its not working. thats the point of the thread

Answer (score -1):

Refer below link :
https://www.w3resource.com/angular/angular-singleton-service.php

you need to register your service in app.module.ts as provider.

```
providers: [{provide: Service}]
```

Comment: No need. "Beginning with Angular 6.0, the preferred way to create a singleton service is to set providedIn to root on the service's @Injectable() decorator. " from: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service